# Simple WCF Sample failing

Tags: wcf

This is a very simple WCF sample and I can't find why is failing.

This is defined in a WCF Class Library project

This is the interface defining the contract:

```
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()> _
    Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    <OperationContract()> _
    Function Ping() As Boolean

End Interface
```

This is the implementation of the interface:

```
<ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults:=True)> _
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData
        Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
    End Function

    Public Function Ping() As Boolean Implements IService1.Ping
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, in a console application called Server, I added a service reference to the service defined above. I create the service host as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   try
   {
      ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceReference.Service1Client));
      NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

      serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceReference.IService1), netTcpBinding, "net.tcp://localhost:9007/Service/");

      Console.WriteLine("Service started at net.tcp://localhost:9700/Service");

      serviceHost.Open();

      Console.WriteLine("Host opened");
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      Console.Read();
   }
   finally
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Service closed");
   }
}
```

Then, in another console application called Client, I added a service reference to the service and create a proxy client as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

   try
   {
       var serviceClient = new Client.ServiceReference1.Service1Client(netTcpBinding, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9007/Service/"));
       serviceClient.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

       Console.WriteLine("Pinging server");               

       if (serviceClient.Ping())
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Getting Data");

          var result = serviceClient.GetData(1);

          Console.WriteLine("Result is " + result);
       }
       else
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Server is not responding");
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I run `Server.exe` it shows *Service started at net.tcp://localhost:9700/Service*

When I run `Client.exe` it shows *Ping the server*

Then I get an error in the WCF Class Library project that I cannot debug and finally an exception in `Client.exe` saying

> *This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:9007/Service/ did
>   not receive  a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The
>   time allotted to this op eration may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.  This may be because the se rvice is still processing the
>   operation or because the service was unable to sen d a reply message. 
>   Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting  the
>   channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout
>   property)  and ensure that the service is able to connect to the
>   client.*

Being that simple and running local in my laptop I don't think there is a problem with timeouts or something like that.

Could anyone shed some light ... I'll appreciate it

Comment: Your service is hosted on port 9700 and in client you are referring the port number to be 9007.

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints a static string before opening the server, and then prints a string after opening the server:

```
Console.WriteLine("Service started at net.tcp://localhost:9700/Service");

serviceHost.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Host opened");
```

You said that you see the first message, but you **never said you see the second message**. Without seeing that message, I am thinking something might be wrong with your call to serviceHost.Open();

Here is an example of using NetTcpBingings in WCF
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article704-using-nettcpbinding-in-wcf-.aspx

Sometimes it helps to start from someone elses code, and modify it from there.